# Live agent chat inside a modal or iframe

Tags: liveagent

I am currently trying: `onclick="liveagent.startChatWithWindow('XXXXXXXXXXX' , 'salesforceChat')" src="XXXXXXXXXXXX" />` with the SalesForce `<img />` snippet. I am referencing an iframe whose id and name are `salesforceChat`. I am not seeing anything that I can click on to initiate the chat using this method. Any recommendations?

I am trying to achieve something that looks like: [image]

Answer (score 0):

The Snap-Ins tool for Live Agent is the route we are pursuing for this. It's got some limitations for sure, but is far better than the pop-up windows.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=snapins_chat_overview.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

Change your clickjack protection level to no protection for your visualforce pages on live agent. It will work.